# Countdown timer with pause in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This code has been used before as a very stable countdown timer in the countdown (other countdown codes sometimes countdown as double or triple counts).

How can I the pause the countdown timer? For instance when people go to a break in 15 minutes. I would like the counter to stop for 15 minutes and then start up again from where the counter paused.

When I use `Application.Wait` the timer still runs in the background in the `Do While Loop`.

```
Sub NewTimer()
Dim Start As Single
Dim Cell As Range
Dim CountDown As Date

Start = Timer

Set Cell = Sheet1.Range("B1")    'This is the starting value.
CountDown = TimeSerial(0, 3, 0)    'Set takttime
Cell.Value = CountDown

Do While Cell.Value > 0
    'Update the cell. Timer - Start is the number of seconds
    'that have elapsed since we set Start.

    If Time >= TimeValue("08:45:00") And Time <= TimeValue("09:00:00") Then 'Pause in 15 minutes
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(Range"A14").Text))                                             
    ElseIf Time >= TimeValue("11:55:00") And Time <= TimeValue("12:25:00") Then 'Pause in 30 minutes
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(Range("A14").Text))    
    ElseIf Time >= TimeValue("14:00:00") And Time <= TimeValue("14:05:00") Then 'Pause in 5 minutes
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(Range("A14").Text))    
    Else: Cell.Value = CountDown - TimeSerial(0, 0, Timer - Start)
    End If      
    DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-tutorial/countdown-timer-in-excel_1557.html) perhaps?

Comment: `Timer` is always "running" because it is a Function which "returns a Single data type, representing the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight of the current day." So even while you use `Wait` method, that does not do anything except pause the thread execution. You may need to add the length of the pause (in seconds?) to the `CountDown` value.